# Timeout in a connection to a DHCP server

Tags: networking, dhcp, avahi, timeout

I want to configure my `eth0` interface using an external DHCP server (resident in my subnet), so I edited `/etc/network/configure` with the lines

```
auto eth0  
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

but I also want to use avahi autoconfiguration when the DHCP server is down.

So I tried `ifup eth0` when the server is down, and after a certain amount of time it fails, but the interface `eth0:avahi` is correctly configured.
What I'm looking for is a way to decrease the amount of time spent trying to connect to a DHCP server.

And ... is this the right way to use avahi when there's no DHCP server?

Answer (score 13):

For setting DHCP client timeout from CLI read [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/dhclient3.8.html).

You can also just configure DHCP clients configuration file. You can find the guide for that [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/dhclient.conf.5.html). On my 12.04 the dhclient.conf  file that you need to edit is uder /etc/dhcp/

So from CLI open the file with this:

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

Scroll to the line where it says "#timeout 60;" and remove the "#" sign.
Change the number to set the timeout in seconds.
Press Ctrl + X to exit the editor and save the changes.

If you can't wait until the next reboot then to force Ubuntu to reacquire a new IP address from the DHCP server run:

```
sudo dhclient -r
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to set:

```
timeout 10;
backoff-cutoff 0;
initial-interval 0;
retry 15;
```

In /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf.

See dhclient.conf manpage (`man dhclient.conf`) for reference.

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed my issue with NetworkManager not being able to get an IP address from the DHCP server (4 port gigabit router).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about avahi but the default configuration file is /etc/network/interfaces. You can place those lines there and dhcp should give you the ipaddress right away.
if you need a static ip address when the dhcp server is down you can set up an alias for eth0 or manually configure it using `ifconfig eth0 x.x.x.x`

Comment: Thank you. But what I really want is that if there isn't a dhcp server, so avahi can set up a link-local address by its own. This happens, but after a "long" time. Is it possible to reduce this time? I just want to set a timeout for a dhcp connection ...