# Ubuntu 16.04 systemd service waits for dhclient to finish when using etc/network/interfaces

Tags: 16.04, networking, dhcp, systemd

I have a 16.04 Desktop box that connects to the internet via WiFi. For ease of remote management, `wlan0` is configured via `/etc/network/interfaces` instead of network manager.

I have a `systemd` service that is enabled to start on boot. This service is set to start after `default.target` like so:

```
[Unit]
After=default.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node main.js"
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

This service starts immediately if I boot up the box in range of its wifi network, because dhclient immediately receives an IP. But if I boot up my system where it can't get on the wifi, my service sits around and waits for dhclient to give up before kicking off. This service waits precisely the 300 seconds specified in the `/etc/dhclient/dhclient.conf` `timeout 300` stanza.

My understanding of `After=default.target` was that it would *NOT* wait on network. `After=network.target` is the tool to do that. If I configure my wifi with Network Manager instead of `/etc/network/interfaces`, the service gets started immediately regardless of network availability.

How can I get my service to start regardless of the status of `dhclient` while still using `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, it appears, is to use the mysterious `allow-hotplug` statement in `/etc/network/interfaces` as I learned from https://askubuntu.com/a/868445/358498:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
...
```

`systemd` no longer waits on network to kick of a service that depends on `default.target`. Why `allow-hotplug` makes such a difference is a bit unclear to me, as there is no true "hotplug" event going on in my system. [One resource](http://www.shallowsky.com/linux/networkSchemes.html) says:

> There's not much documentation on what allow-hotplug actually does. man interfaces (a fairly good man page, BTW) implies that ifup will refuse to bring up an interface unless allow-hotplug is set; but if the network is being started via /etc/init.d/networking start either way, why do different things happen depending on whether allow-hotplug is present? It's all very confusing, but take my word for it, you need allow-hotplug if you're using PCMCIA or Cardbus (or probably USB).